# Windows 7, file properties, date modified, how do you show seconds?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-explorer, file-management, date-time

Anyone know a way to immediately show the seconds of a file's date modified property in the GUI? So if you create a file, any file in any directory, right-click and choose Properties, the date modified (if it's recent) will say something like "**dd/mm/yyy hh:mm, one minute ago**" - reminder this is in Windows 7. Windows XP did it normally. Then they changed something.

If you wait a while, eventually you'll see the seconds, I'm not sure how long a while is, but this is incredibly annoying if you want to troubleshoot something that relies on the *seconds* of timestamps... is there a setting? registry key I can change perhaps?

I'm literally using Chrome, pasting in the path of the directory to be able to see the seconds quickly (as a workaround) but would be nice to be able to use Win7.

Comment: "Then they changed something." i sense another case of 'user anxiety' :)

Comment: This is yet another example of Microsoft’s *The Great Dumbing-Down of Windows*. Instead of pushing computer novices (what’s left of them) to learn computers and provide more advanced users with the power they desire, they keep simplifying everything for the lowest-common-denominator-celebutant-brained user and aggravating the rest of us by not even providing a *power-user* mode. `:-|`

Comment: @Molly, What is user anxiety? Is there even such a term?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

I found a solution at http://www.nicholasoverstreet.com/2010/03/windows-7-annoyance-file-properties/.

Go to 'Control Panel' → 'Region and Language' → 'Additional Settings' → Date tab.

Remove the string `dddd` (e.g. change it to `ddd`) click 'Apply' and it should work fine.

#### Explanation:

'Rightclick file properties' uses the value  `"Long Date" + empty_space + "Long Time"`. Long date is 'dddd, d MMMM yyyy' by default, and 'Long Time' is `h:mm:ss tt`. However, it looks like as long as you have the string `dddd` in 'Long Date', it [may sometimes](https://superuser.com/questions/91287/windows-7-file-properties-date-modified-how-do-you-show-seconds#comment1250913_114117) **ignore** your 'Long Time' settings, overriding it with "x minutes ago".

Comment: Nice find! Inconvenient, but at least it’s something. I just figure that this is a bug as opposed to a feature and may be “fixed” in the future.

Comment: However, this only works if we right click the file and select properties. This still doesn't fix the problem that Windows Explorer is not showing the Long Time but the Short Time.

Comment: I always set both time formats to HH:mm:ss .

Comment: Thank you greatly.  But is there a way to add seconds in the list view in explorer?  Or even by command line with 'dir' ?   (der-da-derp)

Comment: In Windows 10, open 'Control Panel' -> 'Region' -> 'Additional Settings' -> Date tab.  Change the `Long Date`to "ddd, MMMM d, yyyy".  Now go back to a file's properties tab in Windows Explorer and it shows the seconds.

Answer (score 29):

I've been looking at the same problem and as far as I can tell, no there isn't a way.

However, I've been using a workaround that has satisified what I needed it for so hopefully it will help you.  The following command, when run from a command line in the directory in question, will print out the file names and the modified date down to seconds:

```
forfiles /c "cmd /c echo @file @ftime"
```

I hope that might be of some use to people.

Comment: I am in an enterprise network and cannot install any software without a good reason why it would benefit everyone else in the network. I was surprised I could open cmd, though. For users without admin rights and who only need to see the file time stamp with seconds, this is the quickest solution.

Answer (score 17):

You can view the file creation/modification time quickly in [PowerShell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell):

```
PS C:\Users\mskfisher> $file = C:\windows\notepad.exe
PS C:\Users\mskfisher> $file = Get-Item C:\windows\notepad.exe
PS C:\Users\mskfisher> $file.CreationTime

Monday, July 13, 2009 6:56:36 PM


PS C:\Users\mskfisher> $file.LastAccessTime

Monday, July 13, 2009 6:56:36 PM


PS C:\Users\mskfisher> $file.LastWriteTime

Monday, July 13, 2009 8:39:25 PM
```

Inspired by [a TechNet blog post using PowerShell for some other crazy tricks](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2008/05/08/how-can-i-use-windows-powershell-to-report-back-the-name-and-creation-date-for-files-containing-a-specified-string-value.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the tip. It’s a shame that we have to go to such lengths for something so simple. Even the command-prompt refuses to show it. `:-|`

Comment: `Get-ItemProperty C:\Windows\Notepad.exe | Format-List` is a shortened version :) https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-itemproperty?view=powershell-7

Answer (score 16):

It's important to note that Windows *does* show seconds. The hiding of seconds only happens in the main Explorer window:

[image]

But Andrew wasn't asking about the main Explorer window, he was asking about the the **Right-click** -> **Properties** dialog, which **does** show seconds:

[image]

### If it works on Properties, why not in the main window?

The reason you don't see seconds, is that it was a usability decision to remove them (99% of users don't care about the second a file was last modified).

To accomplish this, the shell team is calling [GetTimeFormatEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd318131(VS.85).aspx), using the flag asking for it to remove seconds:

```
GetTimeFormatEx(..., TIME_NOSECONDS, ...);
```

which returns the **Short time** format::

[image]

with any seconds (`ss`)<sup>1</sup> stripped out.

<sup>1</sup>Even though the default en-US locale does not specify **ss** in the **Short time** format; `TIME_NOSECONDS` will remove any `ss` even if there was. <sub>*Nor would i obey that command even if you were.*</sub>

**Edit**: If you **want** to see the time a file was modified (down to the second), then use the Windows GUI. It shows you the time a file was modified (down to the second):

[image]

If you don't want to use the Windows GUI to see the time a file was modified (down to the second), then don't use it.

**Edit 3/26/2015**: The Windows UI will always show the modified time down to the second - even if the file has been modified very recently:

[image]

**Edit 1/28/2016**: Included Windows 10 screenshot to show that Windows 10, like Windows 7, 8, and 8.1, **do** show seconds.

Comment: Unfortunately this is correct. Even adding `ss` to it does not make the seconds show in Explorer, the command-line, the tray-clock, etc. It’s as though they said, *Hey, we made it easy for you to customize things the way you like, but only so long as they conform to the way **we** like*. `>:-(`

Comment: @Ian, "99% of users don't care about resolution up to seconds"? Where did you get that statistics from? This thread already has 24k views.

Comment: Microsoft made it (very) slightly better for users who don't care about seconds, but much worse for users who care. I'm glad there is a solution (the dddd => ddd trick)

Comment: @Pacerier 24,000 / 300,000,000 = 0.008%.

Comment: @IanBoyd, That's assuming everyone who wanted that feature actually ended up on this thread. Nope.

Comment: The windows GUI does NOT always show time to the second. If the modified date is very recent, it will show, for example, "Today, March 26, 2015, 10 minutes ago".

Comment: @RossPresser, I second that. You **must** remove `dddd` as stated by [the post above](http://superuser.com/a/470017/78897). If you do not: The dates will not show the "x minutes ago" if x is 0, But once x is no longer 0, they show it: http://i.stack.imgur.com/CQp4M.png Tested on Win 8.1 NTFS.

Comment: I think this explanation only applies to Windows 7. In Windows 8 and above, the time is completely relative and fuzzy ("8 hours ago"). GetTimeFormatEx() does not return such a string. The "solution" remains the same, and quite usable. However, it's more of a workaround because 'ddd' is a short format day name, so you have to sacrifice the time format to get absolute timestamps back. I wish Microsoft would implement an option in Explorer itself.

Comment: @djs Updated answer with screenshot from Windows 10 showing that file properties *does* show seconds.

Comment: @djs - What you said confuses me. [I don't know what you mean by "sacrifice the time format".] So to clarify, on Windows 10, "Change date & time formats", if you pick a Long Date that does not have "dddd, " in front, then it will completely eliminate the "Today", etc. stuff. You'll see the full Long Date and Long time.

Comment: @Pacerier Hmm, lets see the numbers. According to http://www.worldometers.info/computers/ , there are over *one billion* pcs in use worldwide [including non-Windows].  There are about 20 million programmers, so if every programmer hates this limitation, that's 20/1000 = 2 percent of users. Not every programmer uses Windows, and not every programmer cares about this topic, so 99% is about right - unless there is evidence that a substantial number of non-programmers also pay attention to file times in seconds. :)

Comment: This answer is wrong, it does NOT show the seconds, screenshot here: https://imgur.com/WNzbzE6

Comment: @jitbit Did you change your Windows preferences to indicate that you want to see seconds? Because when you tell Windows you want to see seconds, it  **does** show seconds. Screenshot of Windows 10 right now here: https://i.imgur.com/j46ZPaB.png

Comment: @IanBoyd I did not change anything it's the default setting for Win 2016, editing the settings was the answer

Answer (score 5):

According to [Microsoft Answers](https://web.archive.org/web/20100212214252/http://social.answers.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vistaappearance/thread/5ec0ea23-776e-4163-8106-4651c7c6af4a): (Archived, Jan. 2010)

> Unfortunately we don’t know why this was removed; it’s on the developers’ side of things and out of our realm of “in-the-know”.

As you specified Chrome (and Firefox) will display seconds.

I just loaded XP pro in vmware, and saw the default for XP is sans seconds.  Then I checked GNU `ls` on both Linux and Cygwin, no seconds displayed (by default).  Granted you can do `ls -l --time-style=full-iso` to get the granularity you need.  I guess I never really thought of needing that level of detail.

Comment: So the developers are unilaterally making UI-design decisions? This is exactly the sort of thing that gives a company a bad name.

Answer (score 0):

[fileTweak](http://www.febooti.com/downloads/filetweak/) is a program that adds a tab in Explorer properties.  It is mainly used to change the date/time, but it will display seconds.  Unfortunately it isn't free.

That said, I thought there was a free add-in that basically did the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a free Windows Explorer add-on to display created, modified, access times with seconds, try [stexbar](https://code.google.com/p/stexbar). It adds a tab to a file's properties that allows changing the created, modified, access times and it displays the current times with seconds.

See [here](http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/change-file-date-timestamp-from-file-properties-in-windows) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Explorer++ shows seconds.  I used that for this problem.

https://explorerplusplus.com/download

Answer (score -1):

You can change the default "Short time format" by going to:

Region & Language -> Additional Settings -> Time Tab -> Short time

Simply set this value to: h:mm:ss tt and you'll have seconds shown on file properties now.

Comment: Wrong. Have you not read [Ian's answer](http://superuser.com/a/114117/78897) above? The file properties is affected by the **Long Time** not the **Short Time**. And as for winexplorer, even if you set the **Short Time** to `h:mm:ss tt`, it would still ignore the seconds because the flag is used to remove the seconds: `GetTimeFormatEx(..., TIME_NOSECONDS, ...);`