# get exact file create time windows 7

Tags: windows-7

I'm trying to figure out exactly when I created a file. Windows 7 thinks I don't know how to subtract two times, and tells me it was created "1 hour ago." I need a little more detail than this, but I can't seem to find a setting to toggle this "feature" off.

Example below:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also enable the *Date Created* column in Explorer:

[image]

Comment: This is great. Obviously it'd be nice to have it in my prompt, but this eliminates the need to open the prompt at all. Can't believe I didn't think of this.

Comment: Which prompt? The command-prompt? If you want the created date to be displayed in the command-prompt by default instead of the modified date, then you can [create] the `dircmd` environment variable (or just set it temporarily with the `set` command): `dircmd=/TC`

Comment: Prompt is the wrong word. I meant the dialog in the screenshot above.

Comment: Ah, okay. Unfortunately in Windows Vista and up, they "simplified" a lot of aspects of the UI (for who knows what reason). As such, they just don't show the information that people want like they did in XP (the [*Properties* dialog in XP](http://www.anti-forensics.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/02/lastaccess1.png) *does* show the full timestamp).

Comment: [ClassicShell](http://classicshell.sourceforge.net/features.html) is a shell-extension for Windows 7 that reverts a lot of functionality to that of XP, but unfortunately this is not currently one of them, though you could [request it](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?group_id=290975&atid=1230791).

Comment: @Synetech On a slightly unrelated note, do you know of any programs or extensions that enable/restore the old (XP) Disk Defrag interface?

Comment: No, but the [XP defragger](http://www.serverwatch.com/img/working.jpg) was actually a licensed copy of [Executive Diskeeper 6](http://www.serverwatch.com/img/working.jpg), so you may be able to get a copy of that. though [newer versions](http://img862.imageshack.us/img862/8827/v1509510x64.jpg) are also different.

Answer (score 2):

Found this interesting question on the subject: [Windows 7, file properties, date modified, how do you show seconds?](https://superuser.com/questions/91287/windows-7-file-properties-date-modified-how-do-you-show-seconds)

In my opinion, extending the properties window with [something like SKTimeStamp](http://code.google.com/p/stexbar/)  is easier than opening the shell every time (see the bottom 2 screenshots in their google code site).

Comment: I suppose I could get a shell extension. I definitely wouldn't want to open the command prompt every time I want to see the create time... Still frustrating to see a regression for the sake of "usability"

Answer (score 1):

You always have the option of using the `dir /T` command in the command prompt.  Shows exact time and dates.

Comment: You want the 'C' version of T (so to speak)

Comment: I like it, but when I have the info right in front of me, I'd rather not go to the command prompt for it... I mean it's right there!

Comment: It does not. It only shows the time to the minute, not to the second.

Answer (score 0):

I found XDir, a command line utility. http://download.cnet.com/XDir/3000-2248_4-10508433.html . You can decide what file properties are listed.

e.g.

XDir  L:\luajit-2.0\src*   "/Form=*f *O *o *d *t"

that shows a filename , creation date and modification date exactly

```
L:\luajit-2.0\src\lib_base.c 31/05/2015 12:20:46 31/05/2015 12:20:46
L:\luajit-2.0\src\lib_bit.c 31/05/2015 12:20:46 31/05/2015 12:20:46
L:\luajit-2.0\src\lib_debug.c 31/05/2015 12:20:46 31/05/2015 12:20:46
L:\luajit-2.0\src\lib_ffi.c 31/05/2015 12:20:46 31/05/2015 12:20:46
L:\luajit-2.0\src\lib_init.c 31/05/2015 12:20:46 31/05/2015 12:20:46
L:\luajit-2.0\src\lib_io.c 31/05/2015 12:20:48 31/05/2015 12:20:48
L:\luajit-2.0\src\lib_jit.c 31/05/2015 12:20:48 31/05/2015 12:20:48
L:\luajit-2.0\src\lib_math.c 31/05/2015 12:20:48 31/05/2015 12:20:48
L:\luajit-2.0\src\lib_os.c 31/05/2015 12:20:48 31/05/2015 12:20:48
L:\luajit-2.0\src\lib_package.c 31/05/2015 12:20:48 31/05/2015 12:20:48
L:\luajit-2.0\src\lib_string.c 31/05/2015 12:20:48 31/05/2015 12:20:48
L:\luajit-2.0\src\lib_table.c 31/05/2015 12:20:48 31/05/2015 12:20:48
L:\luajit-2.0\src\lj.supp 31/05/2015 12:20:48 31/05/2015 12:20:48
L:\luajit-2.0\src\ljamalg.c 31/05/2015 12:21:00 31/05/2015 12:21:00
L:\luajit-2.0\src\lj_alloc.c 31/05/2015 12:20:48 31/05/2015 12:20:48
L:\luajit-2.0\src\lj_alloc.h 31/05/2015 12:20:48 31/05/2015 12:20:48
L:\luajit-2.0\src\lj_api.c 31/05/2015 12:20:48 31/05/2015 12:20:48
L:\luajit-2.0\src\lj_arch.h 31/05/2015 12:20:48 31/05/2015 12:20:48
```