# Disable relative timestamps

Tags: windows-8

I recently got over a problem. For short ranges, the properties dialog displays relative timestamps like "2 hours ago". Normally I am fine with that, but at internet shortcuts I cant see the exact date anywhere.

[image: properties dialog showing relative timestamps]

Is there any way to turn this feature off?

Answer (score 0):

See https://superuser.com/a/470017/224740

From the Start Screen, type **Region**, select **Settings**, then select the **Region** shortcut.

Either select the second option form the **Long date** drop down list (MMMM, d, yyyy), or select **Additional settings...** | **Date** tab, and delete the first "d" from the Long date string.