# How does Window Explorer order files when the creation date/time is the same?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer

I unzipped files from an archive, and see the date and time of creation are same. How then does Windows Explorer sort them, since the sort order seems not based on other criteria like modified date or alphabet?

[image]

Comment: The resolution of create time is small number of milliseconds (~10). Windows Explorer just shows you the minutes.

Comment: Perhaps they are not sorted. Or, as Michael Harvey noted above, the file at the top was really the first extracted, and Explorer is sorting on down-to-the centisecond data it does not show us.

Comment: That's certainly a good question, but there have been similar discussions on Super User before:  [Windows 7, file properties, date modified, how do you show seconds?](https://superuser.com/questions/91287/windows-7-file-properties-date-modified-how-do-you-show-seconds)

Comment: Windows is sorting the files by the actual date which has better resolution than displayed. The dates may appear to be identical but in fact they are not.

Comment: @Run5k: Thank you for finding that! However, the solution therein is Win7 specific, and the settings for Win10 are different.

Comment: @user75875 Which version of Windows is in use?

Comment: @K7AAY, absolutely!  But that is why I specifically emphasized that the previous question I referenced was merely *"similar,"* and not a possible duplicate. That being said, it should be pointed out that the OP didn't actually tell us which version of Windows they were using.  Last but not least, I know that the entire community appreciates your contributions and I see that you are relatively new to editing on-the-fly.  When you do, you probably shouldn't remove the `windows` tag while you add the `windows-explorer` tag.  Ultimately, this is still a Windows question.  Thanks for your help!