# Windows - display exact time instead of "1 hour ago"

Tags: windows-10

This is really driving me nuts! Even Windows 10 went for this useless fashion in time reporting!!

[image]

How do I get Windows 10 to report exact time instead of this?

Comment: What build version are you running?

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator 1803 (OS Build 17134.829), Windows 10 Enterprise (c) 2018

Comment: @harrymc No no, this should rather be duplicate of https://superuser.com/q/91287/93604